# If not using genstrings, any benefit to NSLocalizedString over localizedStringForKey:value:table:?

Tags: ios, cocoa, internationalization

If one is not going to use the [genstrings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) console tool to create *.strings* files, is there any benefit to using the [NSLocalizedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) macros rather than directly calling the NSBundle [localizedStringForKey:value:table:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/localizedStringForKey%3avalue%3atable%3a) method?

Those macros call that same NSBundle method. So is support of *genstrings* the only purpose to those macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `NSLocalizedString` definition:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

it becomes clear that `NSLocalizedString` just calls `localizedStringForKey:` with default arguments while also allowing for the specification of a comment (which is ignored by `localizedStringForKey:`.)

Thus, `localizedStringForKey:` is suited for:

1. handling multiple string tables;
2. specifying a custom-return value when no translation is found (`value` arg).

`NSLocalizedString` on the contrary:

1. is more suited to the simplest (most common?) case (just one string table);
2. is more compact;
3. allows to specify a contextual comment.

When to use one or the other?

IMO, the biggest criteria is if you have multiple string tables. If so, you have to use `localizedStringForKey:`, otherwise `NSLocalizedString` will do just fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

They're also shorter to type and easier to read. There are times when you need to use the underlying method calls (such as non-standard strings files, which I have pretty often), but generally `NSLocalizedString()` is much more convenient. It's also easier to audit (see [find_nonlocalized](https://github.com/iosptl/ios6ptl/blob/master/ch17/find_nonlocalized) for an example of this).